# MySQL Double jeopardy

Tags: mysql, jsp

I couldn't really find any info on this subject and I want to ask someone that has had this problem before.

I'm making an application with JSP and MySQL. My question is when I have two of the same application opened and both on the same page. I click on a link in my First application that updates a column in MySQL telling me that it's onto the next step (1->2).

BUT!
in Application Two looks like it hasn't changed. and I click on the link that takes me to the same page where still in MySQL it says that the column has already moved on.

Does anyone know of a way to check a table in MySQL then telling if this is an old packet or not? Using JSP

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about your schema, as this question reads more like a riddle than a technical problem.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: **do not write an essay** explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).